# C# Equivalent to NodeJs Buffer.From then Bitwise Comparison

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, bitwise-operators

I'm spinning my wheels here trying to find the C# equivalent of this NodeJS code. This has been extracted from a much bigger authentication function that has been migrated into C#. I'm unsure what data type Buffer.from produces and tried to replicate the output by using Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes but as I wrote the bytes in the console, I ended up with a different output.

I just need the same final output from out2 to get produced in my equivalent c# function for it to finally work. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
const bitwise = require('bitwise');

testkey = "gEracj9I248GF3yS";
timestamp = "1649302201249";
testid = "8621349";

var testkeyBuffer = new Buffer.from(testkey);
// OUTPUT : 67 45 72 61 63 6a 39 49 32 34 38 47 46 33 79 53
var testkeyArrByte = Uint8Array.from(testkeyBuffer)
// OUTPUT : 103 69 114 97 99 106 57 73 50 52 56 71 70 51 121 83

var timestampBuffer = new Buffer.from(timestamp);
// OUTPUT : 31 36 34 39 33 30 32 32 30 31 32 34 39

var testidBuffer = new Buffer.from(testid);

out1 = bitwise.buffer.or(testkeyBuffer,timestampBuffer);
// OUTPUT : wwvysz;{25:w⌂3yS

out2 = bitwise.buffer.xor(out1,testidBuffer);
// OUTPUT : OADH@N☻{25:w⌂3yS
```

Comment: What encoding are you using in your example? If you interpret the contents of `testkey` as UTF8 characters, the byte representation would be `103 69 114 97 99 106 57 73 50 52 56 71 70 51 121 83`

Comment: That's precisely what I'm getting as well - this is legacy code from a previous developer no longer here. When I dump it into an online nodejs editor that was the dump I received (replit.com/languages/nodejs)

var testkeyBuffer = new Buffer.from("gEracj9I248GF3yS");
console.log(testkeyBuffer)

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("gEracj9I248GF3yS").Select(x => x.ToString("x2"))` --> `"67", "45", "72", "61", "63", "6a", "39", "49", "32", "34", "38", "47", "46", "33", "79", "53"`

Comment: @EricJ. - I just updated the code because I realized the output was the buffer array. When I convert it to Uint8Array it matches what you had

Comment: It seems that you just need to convert all the strings to byte arrays and then OR and XOR the character pairs (i.e. OR testKeyBuffer[0] with timestampBuffer[0], etc. and then XOR out1[0] with testIdBuffer[0], etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it just applies a bitwise operator on two lists, element by element. If one list is longer, then nothing happens to the remaining elements in the other list.

This might be a helper method like

```cs
public IEnumerable<byte> OpOrNop(List<byte> a, List<byte> b, Func<byte, byte, byte> func)
{
    var longer = a;
    if (b.Count > a.Count)
    {
        longer = b;
    }
    
    for (int i=0; i<a.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i < b.Count)
        {
            yield return func(a[i], b[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return a[i];
        }
    }
}
```

so

```cs
string testkey = "gEracj9I248GF3yS";
string timestamp = "1649302201249";
string testid = "8621349";

var testkeyBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testkey);
var timestampBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(timestamp);
var testidBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(testid);

var out1 = OpOrNop(testkeyBuffer.ToList(), timestampBuffer.ToList(), (a, b) => (byte)(a | b));
var out2 = OpOrNop(out1.ToList(), testidBuffer.ToList(), (a, b) => (byte)(a ^ b));

System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(out2.ToArray())
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(out1.ToArray())
```

console output

```
"wwvysz;{25:w\u007f3yS"
"OADH@N\u0002{25:w\u007f3yS"
```

Comment: wow - this is fantastic and frustrating at the same time due to all the time I've wasted on this! Thank you, I'm trying it now